# Copy Video file from CD bad drive

Tags: mac, file-transfer, dvd, file-management

I have a video file AVSEQ01.DAT the size is 800 MB.

I try to copy it from CD Drive to my HDD.

At the way copy process, 400 MB approxymately, error appears that showing unreadable part.

[image]

When the button info does not clicked, I saw the copied file (unfinished) at finder. Just half of the total process

[image]

can I save my unfinished video? It is ok if some of part of the video does not normal, or trimmed.

When I click ok button info, my file is gone.

I am mac user. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the disk?

Comment: yes. Definitely. This is permanent of bad disk. Trust me @DavidPostill.

Answer (score 2):

Not totally sure this will work, but it is worth a shot.

1. Insert the disk into your mac.
2. On your desktop, you should see an icon representing the disk you just put in.   It will have a name associated with it.   For my example, I will just call it CDROM because I do not know what your disk will show up as on your desktop.  You will need this name in a further step.
3. Open a terminal window (via Applications > Utilities > Terminal or via Spotlight and search for terminal)
4. In your terminal window, type the following commands

> ```
> cd /Volumes
> ```

This command will change directory to your /Volumes folder, which is where CD/DVDs are mounted

Now type

> ```
> ls -la
> ```

You should see something similar to this (although your disk most likely wont be called CDROM, replace the word CDROM with whatever the name of the disk is on your system or this wont work at all.

> ```
> drwxr-xr-x@  6 root      wheel    204 Apr 23 11:30 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x  39 root      wheel   1394 Jan 24 13:55 ..
>
> drwxr-xr-x+  2 root      wheel     68 Apr 23 11:30 CDROM
>
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel      1 Apr 17 17:19 Macintosh HD -> /
> ```

See where it says CDROM?   There should be an item named after the name of the disk you have inserted into your computer.   The ls -la command shows the contents of the /Volumes directory in long listing format, and the -a flag will show you all files in that directory.

> ```
> cd CDROM/
> ```

Again, change the word CDROM to whatever your disk is named in the Volumes directory or this wont work at all.

> ```
> cp AVSEQ01.DAT ~/Desktop/
> ```

This last command copies the AVSEQ01.DAT file to your Mac's desktop.   The only reason I am hoping this might work is it probabally wont throw an error that you have to click OK on (hopefully) which stops the file transfer.   Let me know if that works.

If it does work, the video file should appear on your desktop on your mac.   If it spits out errors, please copy paste them here so we can help further or take a screenshot and add it to your question.

Comment: thank you for help. I have try using my own way and now I have saved my video.

Comment: cool glad you were able to get your file back.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys

I have tried this and it seems worked well

- Leave the dialog info showing bad part do not close the dialog
- Using terminal and at the sample, I copy it to flash drive.

Then set unhide the file.

```
cp AVSEQ01.dat /Volumes/MTOHA
chflags nohidden /Volumes/MTOHA/AVSEQ01.dat
```

When I open at windows, my video is fine.

Thank You.